# NoMethodError (undefined method `sanitize_forbidden_attributes' for #<VaSeparateAccount:0x007fc4a233b9b8>) while creating a new separate account

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on rails 4 and having above mentioned error in the following line in my controller's create action

sep_account = VaSeparateAccount.new(params[:separate_account])

Can anyone solve my problem? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Rails < 4.2, you might need to declare all the attributes under the corresponding model. For eg. lets consider a Book model. Under book.rb, you should have all the attributes like the ones below

```
attr_accessible :title, :author, :pages, :description
```

Also, make sure you are not confusing `attr_accessible` with `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 0):

probably it is about your private / protected methods (for `:separate_account`). You should show ur controller. I guess you do not allow to use them on `create` action.